# MainPageView page was instantiate even if no calls made

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to WP programming and need to understand the code written by a contractor.
It seems that MainPageView page(it is the main page) was launched right after Application_Launching() event in the App class.
But I don't see any place calling “new MainPageView” or Navigate to this page.

What I have tried..
1. I searched the entire solution for "MainPageView" to see how this page is called.. but there is no "new MainPageView" or anything that can instantiate the page
2. I set the breakpoints on App class (App.xaml.cs) and MainPageView class and step into but did not find any  indication of what trigger to call MainPageView class

Is there a convention that I am missing? I am having difficulty figuring out the linkage between App class and MainPageView class. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

The default page is referenced in the `Properties/WMAppManifest.xml` file.

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask
     Name ="_default"
     NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml"/>
</Tasks>
```

Also also [App manifest file for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: @mike_jik - No problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to click the little tick icon (on the left) if my answer solved your problem